# How to optimally construct queries asking about the class of an object to eventually find it?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, classification, binary-search

Consider the following problem stated formally:

> You are given $n$ objects $o_1$, $o_2$, ..., $o_n$ and $k$ classes $c_1$, $c_2$, ..., $c_k$, each class containing some objects; an object is chosen. Construct queries asking about the class of the object, such that it can find the chosen object respective to the response to the queries, in no more queries than the minimum possible queries in the worst-case.

Let the state of the objects $o_{a_1}$, $o_{a_2}$, ..., $o_{a_i}$ be indeterminate. If $i = 1$, the object is found and is $o_{a_1}$, as it's the only one that remained indeterminate. Otherwise, letting $b_x$ be the number of the classes that the object $o_x$ is in, ask the query $c_q$, such that $\min(b_q, i - b_q)$ is the maximum. Wait for the response, and remove the objects that are in the class $c_q$ if the answer is "no", and remove the objects that aren't in the class $c_q$, if otherwise. Repeat the process again until $i = 1$.

It seems like this algorithm solves the problem, and finds the object in no more queries than the minimum possible in the worst-case. For example, applying the algorithm on the following classes:

$c_1 = \{l\}, c_2 = \{l, l + 1\}, ..., c_{r - l - 1} = \{l, l + 1, ..., r\}$

would actually binary search on the segment $[l, r]$; it asks $O(log(n))$ queries that is optimal, but is taking $O(n)$ to build each query, that is being done in $O(1)$ when doing binary search. If the problem isn't interactive, it would take $O(n \cdot log(n))$ (it would actually take $\theta(n)$ by doing an accounting, but is still worse than the one running in $O(log(n))$) to find the answer. Can the time complexity of constructing a query [in the general case] be reduced?

Comment: I did not understand the problem statement. What do you mean by "asking query $c_q$", where $c_q$ is a class?